# how to identify accent characters in string - Apex Salesforce?

Tags: unicode, salesforce, apex, unicode-normalization, unicode-literals

we are creating flat file in which placeholders are very important so if consider given name has accented character in it like ÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÛÜÔÖàâäeéèêëîïjôöùûü I need to fix the padding.
So my question is how I can identify these characters in a string other than checking each character individually?

Please help!

I tried like below (\w+), \p{L} but they return true for normal character as well

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( ? ); // what can go here
String stringToInspect = 'Deveé';
Matcher pm = p.matcher(stringToInspect);
```

or any other workaround?